# SQL: Count occurrences that are exclusive from a given value in another column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-redshift

Say we have a dataframe looking like this one below:

```
vendor     product
a          grape
a          peach
a          orange
b          peach
b          strawberry
b          apple
c          grape
c          peach
c          pineapple
```

My goal would be to get a table storing how many items does have each `vendor` that no one else has. So here's how it should look like:

```
vendor     num_exclusive_products
a          1
b          2
c          1
```

Is there any simple and smooth way to reach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this by using the window function `count()` to compute the product count. To ascertain the distinctiveness of each product among vendors, the outer `count()` should exclude products that appear more than once across vendors.

```
with cte as (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by product) as cnt
  from mytable
)
select vendor, count(case when cnt = 1 then 1 end) as num_exclusive_products
from cte
group by vendor
```

[Demo using mysql 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/wyZNY6Qn)

Comment: Without window functions: `select vendor, count(*) from mytable t join (select product from mytable group by product having count(*) = 1) uniq on t.product = uniq.product group by vendor order by vendor`. (I don't post it as answer since this filters out vendors with no unique product - specification says _each vendor_ hence I assume OP expects zeros in this case.)

Comment: Using `LEFT JOIN` and `count(uniq.product)` will help getting zeros

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach inspired by @Tomáš Záluský, using  `LEFT JOIN`, where we perform a left join on the dataset containing unique products :

```
select vendor, count(uniq.product) as num_exclusive_products
from mytable t 
left join ( 
  select product 
  from mytable 
  group by product 
  having count(*) = 1
) uniq on t.product = uniq.product 
group by vendor 
order by vendor;
```

[Demo using mysql 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/JpU-RWwF)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `not exists` to exclude inclusive products before aggregating to count number of exclusive products.

```
select vendor, count(product) as num_exclusive_products
from mytable t1
where not exists (select *
                  from mytable t2
                  where t1.vendor <> t2.vendor and t1.product = t2.product)
group by vendor;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer,using right join to meet needs

select a.vendor,count(vendor) as num_exclusive_products
from mytable as a right join (select product from mytable group by product having count(product)=1) as b on b.product=a.product group by a.vendor ;